# Rails - Use update method only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

So i have a subscription_controller, where i do the logic to subscribe users to Stripe API's subscription model. Now in my destroy method, i cancel the subscription like this:

```
  def destroy
    current_user.update(plan_id: "1")
    customer = current_user.stripe_customer
      ## need to add an column for subscription id to users in order to cancel subscription.
    subscription = Stripe::Subscription.retrieve(current_user.stripe_subscription_id)
    subscription.delete(at_period_end: true)
    ##current_user.update!(stripe_subscription_id: nil)
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "You have canceled your subscription. You will have access until."
    flash[:danger] = "Subscription canceled!"
  end
```

In my update method, i want users to be able to resubscribe, which looks like this:

```
def update


    subscription = Stripe::Subscription.retrieve(current_user.stripe_subscription_id)
    subscription.items = [{
        cancel_at_period_end: false,
        id: subscription.items.data[0].id,
        plan: 'monthly'
      }]
    subscription.save
    current_user.update(plan_id: "2")

    redirect_to root_path
    #customer = current_user.stripe_customer

  end
```

Here's my problem, how do i call the update function only?

Ive tried to add a form_for in the edit html file for subscriptions like so:

## Resubscribe!

```
  <%= form_tag subscription_path, :url => {:controller => :subscription, action: :update} do %>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="RESUBCRIBE Payment" >


  <% end %>
```

But this gives me routing errors.

I also tried `:method => :PUT` with the same results.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What 'routing error' you get? What is in your routes.rb?

Comment: It sounds like what you are trying to do is a soft delete functionality where a record is just marked "deleted" / "canceled" / "suspended" instead of actually removing a row from the db. You can achieve this by just adding an [ActiveRecord::Enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) field. 
You can still keep the same REST semantics of using a DELETE request even if you are not really removing the db entity.

Comment: The reason you're gettting a routing error is that (assuming you're using the resources shorthand in routes.rb) the put expects an id for the resource to update and you're not passing one in your form.